# Comparing two dataframe and output the index of the duplicated row once

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, find

I need help with comparing two dataframes. For example:

The first dataframe is

```
df_1 = 
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   2   2   2   2   2   2
5   5   5   5   5   5   5
6   1   1   1   1   1   1
7   6   6   6   6   6   6
```

The second dataframe is

```
df_2 = 
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   5   5   5   5   5   5
5   6   6   6   6   6   6
```

May I know if there is a way (without using for loop) to find the index of the rows of df_1 that have the same row values of df_2. In the example above, my expected output is below

```
index = 
0
1
2
3
5
7
```

The size of the column of the "index" variable above should have the same column size of df_2.

If the same row of df_2 repeated in df_1 more than once, I only need the index of the first appearance, thats why I don't need the index 4 and 6.

Please help. Thank you so much!

Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index to column for avoid lost index values, last select column called `index`:

```
s = df_2.merge(df_1.drop_duplicates().reset_index())['index']
print (s)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    5
5    7
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df_2.merge(df_1.drop_duplicates().reset_index()))
   0  1  2  3  4  5  index
0  1  1  1  1  1  1      0
1  2  2  2  2  2  2      1
2  3  3  3  3  3  3      2
3  4  4  4  4  4  4      3
4  5  5  5  5  5  5      5
5  6  6  6  6  6  6      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'0':[1,2,3,4,2,5,1,6],
                 '1':[1,2,3,4,2,5,1,6],
                '2':[1,2,3,4,2,5,1,6],
                 '3':[1,2,3,4,2,5,1,6],
                 '4':[1,2,3,4,2,5,1,6],
                '5':[1,2,3,4,2,5,1,6]})

df1=pd.DataFrame({'0':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                 '1':[1,2,3,4,5,66],
                '2':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                 '3':[1,2,3,4,5,66],
                 '4':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                '5':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df1[df1.isin(df2)].index.values.tolist()

### Output
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```